# I need to read input from console and output it in different order using InputStream

Tags: java

I tried to do it this way, and it is not working:

```
  try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
                int i = reader.read();
                while(i != -1) {
                    System.out.println("i = " + i + " = " + (char) i);
                    stack.push((char) i);
                    i = reader.read();

                }
                while(!stack.empty()) {
                    System.out.print(stack.pop());
                }
            }
```

Once it gets into the while(i != -1) loop, it gets into infinite loop.
I found out, that once the program reaches the end of text, the final i = 10. But in Java documentation, I found, that once Reader.read() reaches end of file, it should return -1. That means I can end the loop with while(i != 10), but I want to know why it's returning 10, and not -1.
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you also post your input? <edited>

Comment: You're reading from System.in, the standard input stream. Do you know how to close it on your operating system? How are you running this program?

Comment: @Jason The input can be onl for example abc -> cba

Comment: @Joni This is a problem on hyperskill.org, when I post the solution with -1 there, it is working. But I can't run it with -1 in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: @FilipKovac are you required to use an InputStream? Can you use Scanner?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I am required to use InputStream... Well I don't mind using InputStream, I am capable of making this program in many ways. I just don't understand why the reader.read() is returning 10 at the end of text when it should be returning -1

Comment: The value 10 is ASCII/UNICODE for linefeed (\n).  Note that -1 is not a character - it is a flag value.  If you type '-1' and hit enter, then you will be passing three characters in series: '-', '1', '\n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by checking if **i** is not equal to 10 (end of line is ASCII). When we provide input like "abc" and hit enter we're actually providing **asc\n**. If we check if **\n** (10) has been provided we can break out of the loop.

```java
while (i != -1 && i != 10) {

}
```